# Insert Pandas Timestamp into Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I'm trying to insert a Pandas DataFrame into Mongodb using PyMongo.

```
df.head()
```

[image]

Because the index if the Pandas DataFrame is a `DatetimeIndex`, converting the DataFrame to a `dict` and inserting it to Mongodb:

```
db.testCollection.insert( df.T.to_dict() )
```

gives rise to an error:

```
InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was Timestamp('2016-04-07 09:30:00')
```

How can we convert the `DatetimeIndex` to something else that can be inserted into Mongodb, and later still be able to be converted back to a DatetimeIndex when reading from Mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be that you turn index to `str` before attempting to store away in MongoDB, like this:

```
>> df.index = df.index.astype(str)
>> db.testCollection.insert(df.T.to_dict())
```

When reading the data out of db again later you can turn index to timestamp:

```
>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I hope this helps