# Pandas + PyMongo: Write DataFrame to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe, pymongo

I want to insert pandas DataFrame into MongoDB. However, when I do so, The `timestamp` column (*which is the `index_coloumn` of the Dataframe*) does not get inserted into MongoDB.

Below is my pseudocode code which reproduces the problem:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.ticks
collection = db.STOCK
collection_ohlc = db.STOCK_ohlc

# Read per second ticks data from Mongo into a dataframe
results = collection.find(
    {'timestamp': {'$gte': '2019-01-24T09:15:00', '$lte': '2019-01-24T09:19:59'}})
df = pd.DataFrame(list(results))

# Convert per second ticks data into 1 Minute OHLC Candle
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
ohlc_data = df['ltp'].resample('5min').ohlc()

# Print OHLC candle dataframe
print(ohlc_data)

# Write  the OHLC candle back to Mongo into a new collection STOCK_ohlc
collection_ohlc.insert_many(ohlc_data.to_dict('records'))
```

Here is the output of above `print(ohlc_data)` statement:

```
                       open   high    low   close
timestamp
2019-01-24 09:15:00  286.55  286.7  285.5  285.65
```

Now the code runs fine and `ohlc` values are inserted in MongoDB. However, the `timestamp` column is missing.

Below is MongoShell which lists above inserted record:

```
> db.STOCK_ohlc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6abc6f4994a1bc8c3c08fd"), "open" : 286.55, "high" : 286.7, "low" : 285.5, "close" : 285.65 }
>
```

As we see, the timestamp is missing from above inserted record. This is useless if timestamp is missing.

I tried various `orient` as mentioned in [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) but none of them seem to be inserting into the MongoDB. The only `orient` that inserts data is `records` but then it omits `timestamp`.

Any pointers would be of great help.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the output of `print(ohlc_data.to_dict('records'))`

```
[{'open': 286.55, 'high': 286.7, 'low': 285.5, 'close': 285.65}]
```

Comment: Can you print `ohlc_data.to_dict('records')`? It seems the problem is your row key is type of `timestamp` and Mongo needs string key. Somehow its omitted. Try this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36909509/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36909509/3710490)

Comment: @Valijon, Updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to convert `pd.DataFrame` to `dict`, by default [to_dict(.)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) skips the index and only converts the columns.

A solution would be that you set index as a column before use `to_dict()`:

```py
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
collection.insert_many(df.to_dict('records'))
```

Here is the output of `df.to_dict('records')`:

```py
[{'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-24 09:15:00'), 'open': 286.55, 'high': 286.7, 'low': 285.5, 'close': 285.65}]
```